# Copy weird values from a column with where statement in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, set, sql-update

Hello I have a record that has a SQL in a column. I would like to copy the values and update it to a similar record that shows null for that column. I keep getting a missing comma error.

I am trying 'SET' HDR_LBL_SQL for WHSE 1 like WHSE 2. Any ideas? Thanks

Table: Label_Cnfg
Fields: WHSE, TYPE, HDR_LBL_SQL

| WHSE | TYPE | HDR_LBL_SQL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TICKET | NULL |
| 2 | TICKET | (*See SQL Below) |

HDR_LBL_SQL for WHSE 1

```
Select
ch.case_nbr,
ch.case_nbr case_brcd,
ch.RCVD_SHPMT_NBR,
iwm.PUTWY_TYPE ,
ch.PO_NBR, 
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN to_char(ch.MFG_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY') ELSE 'MIXED' END) MFG_DATE,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN to_char(ch.XPIRE_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY') ELSE 'MIXED' END)XPIRE_DATE,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN to_char(ch.CONS_PRTY_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY') ELSE 'MIXED' END) CONS_PRTY_DATE,   
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN trim(im.dsp_sku) ELSE 'MIXED' END) SKU,

(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN trim(im.dsp_sku) ELSE 'MIXED' END) SKU_BRCD,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN im.sku_desc ELSE 'MIXED' END) SKU_DESC,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN CD.INVN_TYPE ELSE 'MIXED' END) INVN_TYPE,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN CD.INVN_TYPE ELSE 'MIXED' END) BRCD_INVN_TYPE,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN cd.PROD_STAT ELSE 'MIXED' END) PROD_STAT,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN cd.PROD_STAT ELSE 'MIXED' END) BRCD_PROD_STAT,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN cd.batch_nbr ELSE 'MIXED' END) batch_nbr,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN cd.batch_nbr ELSE 'MIXED' END) BRCD_batch_nbr,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN cd.CNTRY_OF_ORGN ELSE 'MIXED' END) CNTRY_OF_ORGN,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN cd.CNTRY_OF_ORGN ELSE 'MIXED' END) BRCD_CNTRY_OF_ORGN,
SUM(cd.actl_qty),' ',' ',' ',' ',' '
from
case_hdr ch
inner join case_dtl cd on ch.case_nbr = cd.case_nbr
inner join item_master im on im.sku_id = cd.sku_id
inner join item_whse_master iwm on im.sku_id = iwm.sku_id 
inner join (select count(distinct(SKU_ID||INVN_TYPE||PROD_STAT||BATCH_NBR)) SKUCOUNT,case_nbr from case_dtl cd where case_nbr = :g_case_nbr group by case_nbr)CASECNT
on CASECNT.case_nbr = cd.case_nbr
where
ch.case_nbr = :g_case_nbr 
and cd.case_seq_nbr = :g_case_seq_nbr
and ch.stat_code in ( '10', '30', '90', '96' )
group by
ch.case_nbr,
ch.case_nbr ,
ch.RCVD_SHPMT_NBR,
ch.PO_NBR,
iwm.PUTWY_TYPE , 
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN to_char(ch.MFG_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY') ELSE 'MIXED' END) ,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN to_char(ch.XPIRE_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY') ELSE 'MIXED' END),
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN to_char(ch.CONS_PRTY_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY') ELSE 'MIXED' END) ,   
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN trim(im.dsp_sku) ELSE 'MIXED' END) ,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN trim(im.dsp_sku) ELSE 'MIXED' END) ,
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN im.sku_desc ELSE 'MIXED' END),
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN CD.INVN_TYPE ELSE 'MIXED' END),
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN cd.PROD_STAT ELSE 'MIXED' END),
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN cd.batch_nbr ELSE 'MIXED' END),
(CASE WHEN CASECNT.SKUCOUNT = '1' THEN cd.CNTRY_OF_ORGN ELSE 'MIXED' END)
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: I've never understood the "wisdom" of keeping the text of a SQL statement in a table.  Beyond that, the SQL you show has multiple, contradictory actions for the same CASE evaluation.  How is that working out for you?

Comment: I guess its working because the label works for WHSE 1. I wanted to simplify the approach and see if something like Update label_cnfg
SET HDR_LBL_SQL = (SELECT HDR_LBL_SQL
          FROM label_cnfg
          WHERE WHSE = '2' and lbl_type = 'TICKET')

WHERE WHSE = '1' and lbl_type = 'TICKET';

Comment: You might be right @EdStevens, but did you understood the "wisdom" of SQL that appears out of nothing in *ORM* or is concatenated from literal strings in an application?

Comment: I good practice if you need to aggregate expressions is to define a subquery that calculates the expressions and a query that `group by` the result columns. Apart from this I did not get what is your problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
update Label_Cnfg set 
HDR_LBL_SQL=(select HDR_LBL_SQL from Label_Cnfg where WHSE=2 and TYPE='TICKET')
where WHSE=1 and TYPE='TICKET';
```